# error in execution of insert to table using mysql connector in c/c++

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

```
sql::Driver     *driver;
sql::Connection *dbConn;
sql::Statement  *stmt; 
try{
    driver = get_driver_instance(); 
    dbConn = driver->connect("tcp://172.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
    stmt = dbConn->createStatement();
    dbConn->setSchema("zabbix");
    res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO table(name,surname) VALUES ('123','33333333')");
}catch (sql::SQLException e)    {
    cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Hello guys, I have the following problem: in this code I am trying to insert data to my table, but when the code arrives to `row execute query` it's going to catch part (`error code: 0`) and data has been inserted, and when I am trying to execute code without the `try/catch`, the program is being blocked.

**Error point:**

```
[First <kbd>F5</kbd>] `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF7B254008 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x00000014AFDDF5F0.`


[Second <kbd>F5</kbd>]: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF7BCEA508 (ucrtbase.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.`
```

which is the cause of this problem? how to use correctly insert to table?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem,
the problem was the following: i changed executeQuery in executeUpdate and code it does not go anymore in catch part (google translate)